# How to optimize call to database with OneToOneField?

Tags: django, database

According to the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/db/optimization/#use-foreign-key-values-directly), to optimize the db access :

> If you only need a foreign key value, use the foreign key value that
> is already on the object you’ve got, rather than getting the whole
> related object and taking its primary key. i.e. do:
>
> ```
> entry.blog_id
> ```

No problem to use with a ForeignKey and it works as intended.
But if I want to do the same with OneToOneField, it is not working :

```
Class CustomUser(Model):
   ...

class Profile(Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        CustomUser,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

Then, if I try to use the same tip as described in the documentation, in a view for example :

```
request.user.profile_id
```

I got the followig error :

```
AttributeError: 'CustomUser' object has no attribute 'profile_id'
```

Of course, it works with `request.user.profile.uid` but it is not the point here because there is an additional query to the DB.
Is it intended ? Is it a con to using OneToOneField ?

Comment: What you are trying to do is called reverse lookup. 
However you can use 
request.user.select_related("profile").profile.uid

Comment: I think he knows how to do that, he looking to optimize the query. What you posted will do the same as `request.user.profile.uid`.

Comment: That is not the point @AshrafulIslam, your response will lead to a query sql, that is what I am trying to avoid.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're doing it in reverse (it's the model `Profile` that has the field `user_id`, and not `CustomUser` that has the field `profile_id`) I think you can't use this optimization. You'd have to move the OneToOneField to `CustomerUser` model. You can still access the object of course, but you're going to hit the database once more.

**Edit**
If possible for your project, this should work:

```
class Profile(Model):
    ...

class CustomUser(Model):
    profile = models.OneToOneField(
        Profile,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
    )
```

```
request.user.profile_id
```

Comment: Like you said, I am afraid I can not optimize it in reverse. In a future project, I will be aware of this problem and use a different link between Profile and CustomUser